# How to find all local files by name using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, command-line-interface

I'm creating a CLI using [Oclif](https://oclif.io/) and want to search for and read all files that match `*.appName.json`.

I tried using `glob.sync("**/*.appName.json")` but that only returns files within the project and ignores files in higher up directories.

I understand that it might not even be possible for security reasons but any tips would be appreciated! (Would prefer a cross-platform solution but happy to patch together OS specific solutions too).

Comment: I haven't used oclif but have you tried adding `/` at the front, `/**/*.appName.json`. If it doesn't work, you can also get the root using `path` `path.join(path.resolve("/"), "**/*.appName.json")` https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#pathresolvepaths

Comment: Thanks @UgurEren! Adding the / at the front worked perfectly. Please add an answer so I can accept it.